# SQL INNER JOIN duplicate columns

Tags: sql, database, inner-join

I am trying to return some columns from 2 tables which share an ID column using the following browser [database query system](https://datacentral.org.au/services/query/), which reads from the tables shown on [this webpage](https://datacentral.org.au/services/schema/). I believe the way to do this is by using `INNER JOIN` (e.g. see [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)).

```
SELECT  sami_dr2.DR2Sample.CATID,
        sami_dr2.DR2Sample.Mstar,
        sami_dr2.StellarKinematics.PA_STELKIN
FROM    sami_dr2.DR2Sample INNER JOIN sami_dr2.StellarKinematics
ON      sami_dr2.DR2Sample.CATID = sami_dr2.StellarKinematics.CATID;
```

However, when I run this query I get the error message:

> sql: Duplicate columns are not supported. Try using an alias for those columns within the SELECT clause e.g., SELECT t1.CATAID, t2.CATAID becomes SELECT t1.CATAID as t1_CATAID, t2.CATAID as t2_CATAID

But as far as I'm aware the whole point of using the INNER JOIN is to remove duplications as I'm not returning `sami_dr2.StellarKinematics.CATID` in my output table, only `sami_dr2.DR2Sample.CATID`.

I've also found that using `SELECT sami_dr2.DR2Sample.CATID as ID_1, sami_dr2.StellarKinematics.CATID as ID_2` in the selction doesn't fix the problem either.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: NATURAL JOIN and JOIN USING both remove duplicated columns, JOIN ON doesn't.

Comment: Use table aliases and see what happens.

Comment: @Brad  DISTINCT if for rows  ..not for columns

Comment: @scaisEdge, You are right, I was looking at a few questions and commented incorrectly.  So deleted my Comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @user8188120 Remove schema names from select list: `select DR2Sample.CATID` instead of `select sami_dr2.DR2Sample.CATID`. Or use table aliases, they solve the problem too

Comment: Using aliases worked as did removing the schema names from the select list (the latter pointing towards my error in using the whole schema.table.column style in the SELECT statements which was incorrect of me. Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it! :)